# Proof of the orthogonality of a given matrix which involves binomial coefficients

Tags: proof-verification, binomial-coefficients, orthogonality

I'm reading a [paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/obu090mxrctx54e/zelechow1968.pdf?dl=0) (see pages 6 and 7 pf the pdf) which claims that a given $n+1$-dimensional square matrix $C$ is orthogonal. The $kj^{th}$ element of this matrix is given by:

$$C_{kj}=2^{-\frac{n}{2}}\binom{n}{k-1}^{\frac{1}{2}}\binom{n}{j-1}^{\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{\nu=0}^{j-1}(-1)^{n-1-\nu}\binom{n-k+1}{j-\nu-1}\binom{k-1}{\nu}$$

The variable $n$ is a non-negative integer. 
I didn't find any proper proof of the orthogonality of this matrix in the paper or in anywhere else, so I will try to achieve it by myself (or hopefully with some of your help).

To prove that $C$ is indeed orthogonal, one would need to show that:

$$C^T=C^{-1}\Leftrightarrow (C^TC)_{ij}=\delta_{ij}\Leftrightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}C_{ki}C_{kj}=\delta_{ij}\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sum_{\mu=0}^{i-1}\sum_{\nu=0}^{j-1}2^{-n}(-1)^{\mu+\nu}\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n}{i-1}^{\frac{1}{2}}\binom{n}{j-1}^{\frac{1}{2}}\binom{n-k+1}{i-\mu-1}\binom{n-k+1}{j-\nu-1}\binom{k-1}{\mu}\binom{k-1}{\nu}=\delta_{ij}$$

There are too many binomial coefficients to deal in this equation. I really don't know how to simplify it. Can you help me in this one?

Comment: Please link the paper if possible.

Comment: [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bv+%3D+0%7D%5E%7Bj+-+1%7D+(2%5E(-n)+(-1)%5E(u%2Bv)*+binom(n,k-1)*+binom(n,i-1)%5E(1%2F2)+*+binom(n,j-1)%5E(1%2F2)++*binom(n-k%2B1,i-u-1)+*binom(n-k%2B1,j-u-1)*+binom(k-1,u)*+binom(k-1,v))) will at least simplify one sum.

Comment: Just to mention that the paper says that  $C$ is orthogonal because the vectors $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are orthonormal. I can show that if initial and final sets are orthonormal, then the transform matrix is orthogonal. The problem is that I don't to know how to do the proof, when the orthonormality is 
 between initial and final vectors themselves. So, I didn't understand what the authors really meant by that proposition.